# Calendar app take value date(January 1st, 1970) as default in frontend if device language is english[Hongkong SAR china]

Tags: php, magento, calendar, web

Calendar app  take value date(January 1st, 1970) as default in frontend if device language is english[Hongkong SAR china] in my website based on magento framework.Is there any solution to get current time? and the problem is only in Internet Explorer.

here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Boy.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like in IE the date format is being sent incorrectly to your server. Correct the sending or the processing server side. `January 1st, 1970` is the default return for `strtotime` when it can't process the date. For example, https://eval.in/607904.

Comment: how can i correct the sending or the processing server side?

Comment: Modify the datepicker so it always sends in your standard format. You might have to debug in IE to see why it doesn't follow other browsers behavior.... or modify server side so it can handle the IE formatting as well.

Comment: Magento Locale is US English by deafult, so when the OS of browsing laptop is set to English US as input language, the calendar comes out OK.

When the language of browsing laptop is changed to English (Hong Kong) then in Edge or IE the whole calendar comes with 01/01/1970 (we have 30 days view in the calendar and all 30 days show up as 01 Jan 1970)

Comment: I think this is a Magento issue which I haven't worked with, adding code should help others help you though.

Comment: Finally the problem is solved. And the code is here, ( It works in all browser because of its constant English[US] time format and it doesn't care about your browser's language.)

before,
$currentDate = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp());

after,
$currentDate = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(),null, "en_US");

Comment: You should post that as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem is solved. And the code is here, ( It works in all browser because of its constant English[US] time format and it doesn't care about your browser's language.)

before,

```
 $currentDate = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp());
```

after,

`$currentDate = new Zend_Date(Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(),null, "en_US");`